# Optimize JPA Repository Calls

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

In my current application I have a very large list of objects, and I am iterating through all of them in a for loop and calling a JPA Repository `findBy` query on each. The issue with this approach is that it is taking in total roughly 20-30 seconds for all the operations to complete. I am struggling to find a way to optimize the call, because from a user perspective 20-30 seconds is way to long to wait for the data to load.

I have changed the names of most variables but the logic remains the same

```java
@Repository
public interface ObjectDataResultRepository extends JpaRepository<ObjectDataResult, Long>{

    List<ObjectDataResult> findByParameterOneAndParameterTwoAndParameterThreeAndParameterFourAndParameterFive(
            String ParameterOne,
            String ParameterTwo,
            String ParameterThree,
            String ParameterFour,
            String ParameterFive,
    );
```

Currently How I call it.

```java
// This takes 20-30 seconds
for (InputObject input : objects) {
     List<ObjectDataResult> result = objectDataResultRepository.findByParameterOneAndParameterTwoAndParameterThreeAndParameterFourAndParameterFive(inputs... )
     // Add results to list for logic after queries complete
}
```

Comment: Each loop takes little time but since you are doing lot of loops then it takes 20 seconds? Or every loop takes 20 seconds?

Comment: All Loops combined take 20 seconds

Comment: 1) If `results` is the same for some calls, then could put a cache in front of `objectDataResultRepository` to avoid some calls. 2) If each iteration is independent, then could submit each iteration to an executor to run them concurrently.

Comment: The are all independent, and I did not add it in the example for simplicity, but the actual implementation is done through an executor asynchronously

Comment: Watch out, this usage is a known anti-pattern, the N+1 queries problem. If the `InputObject` is an entity, trust the DB and let it join the data. If it is a DTO, use SQL/JPQL `IN` to fetch all the `ObjectDataResult` objects, or at least fetch them in large batches. How exactly, and how you can translate it to JPA, depends on the exact structure of the DB, the entities and the `InputObject`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the problem is that any one query takes little time, but you are having a lot of inputObjects and therefor the summed time is too large.
In this case you might want to look into ways to avoid the loop and fetch all the data in one query. It's a bit hard to give a sure way to make it optimal without knowing your exact DB schema, but since your query has a lot of parameters I'd look into JPA's `CriteriaBuilder` API and use this to create one big query with bunch of ORs and ANDs combined together.

Introductory tutorial on criteria API can be found here: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries

Comment: I've looked into these, but I am a bit confused how I could implement it with the List of objects as a parameter, but also the fact that for each object I return a list

Comment: In the tutorial I linked, check out the end of "3.1. Using Expressions" part (the part about predicates). In each loop you would create a predicate and add it to arraylist. After the loop you would do `.where(predicates.toArray()` and submit the query. You would get it as one big list so it would be up to your application code to somehow take the results and tie them back together with correct inputObjects. As said, it's bit hard to be more specific without knowing your exact use case, but doing one big indexed query is almost always better than doing tens or hundreds of small ones.

Comment: Okay I'll check it out, I appreciate the input!